# Submitting a completely new list to recycler view with list adapter causes flickering/laggy animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

i am using a recycler view with a list adapter. When submitting a list with a completely or almost completely different items the animation doesn't look good. Another problem is that i have no control on the scroll position as scroll to position is not processed as expected. It makes perfect sense to reset the scroll position to zero when the data is changed. 
I ended up setting up a new adapter when switching all the data.
Would be helpful to have a better solution.

I would expect to have a method where you notify the adapter/recycler view that you want to switch all the data without trying to applying the diff mechanism and animating the changes. 
I would like to be able to animate the appearance of the new list but avoid trying to animate what actually changed.

Comment: Do you have multiple `ViewTypes`? and by diff mechanism, do you mean `DiffUtil`? Can you explain a bit more about your requirement or if you can post some code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Yes, I mean 'DiffUtil' and i have in some case multiple view types. I actually encountered this problem twice, one with single type and other with multiple types.